# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource in expressjs

Tags: node.js, express, cors

I've already configured `cors` in my nodejs application as follow:

```
cors = require('cors');

var whitelist = ['http://first.url', 'https://test.cloudfront.net']
var corsOptions = {
    origin: function (origin, callback) {
        if (whitelist.indexOf(origin) !== -1) {
            callback(null, true)
        } else {
            callback(new Error('Not allowed by CORS'))
        }
    }
}

router.get('/home', cors(corsOptions), controller.index);
```

It's working and fetch data from nodejs app from `http://first.url` but when I tested with `https://test.cloudfront.net`, it's not working and return following error.

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://server.cloudfront.net/api/app/home.
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'https://test.cloudfront.net' is therefore not
>   allowed access.

Please let me know how come that error is return. Because of some configuration is missing in cloudfront?

Comment: Did you try to specify credentials:true in cors config?

Answer (score 0):

Browser send before an OPTIONS request to the server to know if it accept cross origin request, just handle OPTIONS request with a simple middleware

```
app.use(function(req,res, next){
   if(req.method == "OPTIONS"){
      res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', "*");
      res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', "POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE");
      res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', "*");
      res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
      return res.sendStatus(200);
    }
    else
      return next();
});
```